# How can I make my multiple buttons and functions expandable

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint

I created a function to add different specific words to a Sharepoint when a button is selected/clicked, but the script is not expandable. How can I make multiple buttons function and function more expandable and grow when another set of words are needed to add to the SharePoint list. It would be nice to not have a growing list of buttons and functions.  My working but not very efficient/expandable.

Code is below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
jQuery(document).on("click", '.picture1', function(){
        InsertItem1();
    });
    
jQuery(document).on("click", '.picture2', function(){
        InsertItem2();
    });
jQuery(document).on("click", '.picture3', function(){
        InsertItem3();
    });
    
jQuery(document).on("click", '.picture4', function(){
        InsertItem4();
    });
});

function InsertItem1() { updateData("Selected"); }
function InsertItem2() { updateData("Field-3"); }
function InsertItem3() { updateData("Field-2"); }
function InsertItem4() { updateData("Field-1"); }
 


function updateData(viewhit) {
    var restendpoint = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Views')/items";
    $.ajax({
        url: restendpoint,
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify({
            __metadata: {
                type: "SP.Data.ViewsListItem"
            },
            Title: "Podcast",
            Views: viewhit
        }),
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
            "X-HTTP-Method": "POST"
        },
        success: function() {
            console.log("Item added to the SharePoint list");
        },
        error: function() {
            console.log("Error Occurred!");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: this `jQuery(document).on("click", '.picture1', function(){ InsertItem1(); });` could be shorten as `$('.picture1').on('click', function() { updateData('Selected'); });`

Comment: For clarification, your *expandable* means a flexible/reusable function which just declare once and capable of handle gworing set of words ?

Comment: Hello Zeikman, thank you for the quick reply and code change.  Yes I like my script to be more flexible/reusable to accommodate the growing list of specific words that is will add to the SharePoint list.  I hope this clarify my aim better.  Thanks again for the assist.

Comment: Ok, I try my best lending you a hand :) Want to make myself more clear, is your element clickable element is having same naming pattern like `.picture1`, .picture2`, and so on ?

Comment: Sound good.  If a different name pattern is necessary I'm ok with changing them.  I used old code to create this concept.  I got it working, now I like to clean it up and make flexible/reusable.  I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Try my best to restructure your code into a more expandable/resuable way.

My approach is to select all element which having class name begin with naming `picture` at first,

```
$('[class^=picture]')
```

then registet event listener to all at once and twitching the arguments using `switch` condition based on element's class name as shown below, not sure if it fits your condition or not.

---

#### Edited:

Suddenly think of another shorter attempt which using an object so I include it in the snippet for your reference.

```js
const controller_object = {
  'picture1': 'Selected',
  'picture2': 'Field-3',
  'picture3': 'Field-2',
  'picture4': 'Field-1'
};

$('[class^=picture]').on('click', function(e) {
  const elementClass = $(this).attr('class');
  
/*/ // add a slash (/) at the beginning of this line to activate 1st attempt
  
  // 1st attempt with switch
  let viewHit;
  
  switch(elementClass) 
  {
    case 'picture1':
      viewHit = 'Selected';
      break;
      
    case 'picture2':
      viewHit = 'Field-3';
      break;
      
    case 'picture3':
      viewHit = 'Field-2';
      break;
      
    case 'picture4':
      viewHit = 'Field-1';
      break;
      
    case 'default':
      break;
  }
  
  updateData(viewHit);
  
  /*/
  
  // 2nd attempt with object controller
  updateData(controller_object[elementClass]);
  
  //*/
});

function updateData(viewhit) { 
  // simple writing to mimic your function calls
  alert(viewhit); 
}
```

```css
[class^=picture] {
  border: 1px dashed black;
  padding: 3px 6px;
  margin: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

[class^=picture]:hover {
  background-color: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="picture1">Picture 1</div>
<div class="picture2">Picture 2</div>
<div class="picture3">Picture 3</div>
<div class="picture4">Picture 4</div>
```

Hope it helps and Happy coding !

Comment: Thank you Zeikman, looks good.  I will give it try.  Look so much efficient then my run at it.  I really appreciate the assist.

Comment: Don't mention it :)